# Submit Perforce CL with no opened files

Tags: perforce

I made my change successfully did a `p4 change` and have a numbered CL.

`p4 describe -c 27701190` indicates it is pending, however `p4 pending` and `p4 opened` indicate "File(s) not opened on this client".

It's not critically important that my client be updated, but I'd like to submit this CL. (I'd also be happy with getting my client situation rectified).

What's the path to either submitting this CL or opening the files involved in this CL on my client?

Comment: It sounds like maybe you made changes to files without ever marking them for edit?

Comment: When you run 'p4 describe' on your changelist, does it list any files that are open for edit (or add or delete).  You have suggested that you've modified a file so I would expect to see that file listed for edit in the output of the describe command.

Comment: wow 27701190 changelists what policy do you have on changes, thats one hell of a count!

Comment: Oh - I see you work at Google :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open the files for edit after the fact (i.e., after you've changed them without telling Perforce you were going to change them).  Just run the edit command and open them in the desired changelist with the -c switch:

```
p4 edit -c 27701190 "//depot/path to files/..."
```